# How to get My Electron Auto updater to work?

Tags: javascript, windows, vue.js, electron, electron-updater

I'm trying to get my Electron Vue.js aplication to update itself when i release a new update in my Github Repro.

I'm packing my app using "electron-builder" and here is my [package.json](https://gist.github.com/ScarVite/ba1cbd2e9e9ee5b9d5652d9f8ab33ade)

I was following [this guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/updates) but it didn't work.

This is the Code for the updater part which is located at the top of the src/main/index.js.

```
const { app, autoUpdater, dialog } = require('electron')
const server = "https://hazel.scarvite.now.sh/"
const feed = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`
autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feed)

setInterval(() => {
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
}, 60000)

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
    const dialogOpts = {
        type: 'info',
        buttons: ['Restart', 'Not Now. On next Restart'],
        title: 'Update',
        message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
        detail: 'A New Version has been Downloaded. Restart Now to Complete the Update.'
    }

    dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts).then((returnValue) => {
        if (returnValue.response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()
    })
})

autoUpdater.on('error', message => {
    console.error('There was a problem updating the application')
    console.error(message)
})
```

I am Hoping that you guys can help me

Comment: I can relate, I've spent days getting my auto updater working. Can you include your `package.json` and the way you package your app e.g. `electron-builder` or `electron-packager`.

Comment: My `package.json` syntax is different to yours. Try removing the `.git` at the end of `repository.url`. Also try changing `build.win.publish` to an object like: `"publish": {"provider": "github"}`. Also it doesn't seem like you're using `electron-builder` to publish your releases, so how do you publish a release on Github?

Comment: Were packing our app with the npm run build -w, which executes "node [.electron-vue/build.js](https://gist.github.com/ScarVite/7b193a94ac8c169ac875e1671874183c) && electron-builder". and it packs it to an exe which we then release it on the repro i linked. if you mean that

Comment: Okay, if my `package.json` syntax suggestions don't work, try releasing the binary on Github with `electron-builder`'s `-p` option. That'll automatically publish the new release on the Github repo. [See docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish#how-to-publish)

Comment: do you mean like that : "npm run build -w -p".
Updated my [package.json](https://gist.github.com/ScarVite/ba1cbd2e9e9ee5b9d5652d9f8ab33ade) btw

Comment: i just noticed another problem: the url "https://hazel.scarvite.now.sh/" doesnt event get pinged by the package app, only by the unpackaged one

Comment: What I mean by the `-p` option is to add ` -p always` to the end of your `electron-builder` script in your `package.json`. So it'd be something like: `"releaseWin": "electron-builder --ia32 -p always"`. [See publishing options](https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish#how-to-publish).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206755/discussion-between-joshua-and-scarvite).

Comment: hi @ScarVite, can you share your package.json (at least the properties required for this question it would be very helpful for me to get hazel to working. When clicking on the link it says 404

Comment: hi @Meilech, i did not get it to work with hazel, idk if it was a misconfiguration problem, but i just simply did not work. I switched over to github releases for updating and described how i got it to work below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Figured it out after a bit of an struggle.
Turns out the zeit.co server i was using wasn't sending the latest.yml. So We can completely remove

```
const server = "https://hazel.scarvite.now.sh/"
const feed = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`
autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feed)
```

and i started working with github instead. We also had to change the autoupdater from electron, as it is deprecated, to electron-builder's autoupdater instead. We imported it like this: `const { autoUpdater } = require("electron-updater");` **Don't forget to `npm i electron-updater`**

In my Package.json i changed my build script so it would directly publish to github as a draft.`node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder -p always`.

I also had to add

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ScarVite/Example-Repro/"
},
    "publish": {
    "provider": "github",
    "releaseType": "release"
},
"build": {
    "productName": "Your App Name",
    "appId": "com.example.yourapp",
    "directories": {
        "output": "build"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
        "icon": "build/icons/icon.ico",
    "publish": [
            "github"
        ]
    },
```

I called  `autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();` in my app.on('ready') and set a intervall, so it checks every 10 minutes

Then on the autoupdater event update-downloaded i sent a dialog asking the user if they want to restart and update the app now or later. If the response was now i called `autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()` and it restarted. the Autoupdater updates the next time you close the app automatically

Comment: Hi, I'm able to update my electron app using the above approach but when I go back and open up the electron app, the auto-update pop-up notifies me again... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use **electron-updater** module

```
const { autoUpdater } = require("electron-updater");

/*checking for updates*/
autoUpdater.on("checking-for-update", () => {
  //your code
});

/*No updates available*/
autoUpdater.on("update-not-available", info => {
  //your code
});

/*New Update Available*/
autoUpdater.on("update-available", info => {
  //your code
});

/*Download Status Report*/
autoUpdater.on("download-progress", progressObj => {
 //your code
});

/*Download Completion Message*/
autoUpdater.on("update-downloaded", info => {
 //your code
});

/*Checking updates just after app launch and also notify for the same*/
app.on("ready", function() {
 autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
});
```

Comment: still doesn't work.
i Uploaded the entire [index.js](https://gist.github.com/ScarVite/54a46d4b145ceb7bc5752ed79efa3917). hope this helps

Comment: I am using in script object of package.json

`"dist": "build --win" //for local build 
"ship": "build --win -p always" //to ship the build for auto update`

did you check the console log for auto-update?
i am not able to see the electron-updater module in dependencies object of package.json

`Dev-dependecies
electron-builder v20.31.0

Dependencies
electron-updater v3.1.2`

Comment: i have `"electron-updater": "^4.2.0"`in my local package.json and im using `node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder -p always -w` to build.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the feed url is wrong

```
const server = "https://hazel.scarvite.now.sh/"
const feed = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`
```

output:

```
https://hazel.scarvite.now.sh//update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}
```

Make sure you remove the last slash from the feed url.

Comment: already tried it, it not working with my hazel link had to do with me not upload latest.yml and the blockmap and there is an issue with zeit.co's service i figured the answer out yesterday