# Can someone explain how I can add and use 'electron-auto-updater' to my electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, package.json

I'm currently trying to figure out how to add an auto-updater to my electron app so I don't have to keep updating my google drive link for the app.

I've seen some videos but none really explain how to setup your package.json or how to get a .git file etc.

Currently, my package.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "notify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A prototype version of Notify",
  "main": "./Javascript/Main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.2.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.3.1",
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.5",
    "update-electron-app": "^2.0.1",
    "ws": "^7.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "electron": "^11.2.0",
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"electron .\" \"electron .\"",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . Notify --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32  --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Notify\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . Notify --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I want to set up my package.json for windows devices (preferably others too but mainly windows).

If anyone has any videos / links on how to use the electron-auto-updater with ease please link them aswell. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some of the results of a search for _"electron auto update"_): [autoUpdater | Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater) (incl. [a detailed guide about how to implement updates in your application](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/updates)), [GitHub - matiastucci/electron-auto-updater-example: Electron auto updater example](https://github.com/matiastucci/electron-auto-updater-example), [javascript - How to get My Electron Auto updater to work? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922073/how-to-get-my-electron-auto-updater-to-work)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: _"If anyone has any videos / links..."_ - Asking for off-site resources is off-topic -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Andreas as i've said, i have searched up tutorials, read up the APIs, and searched for a good 2 hours yesterday. I didn't feel like I was getting anywhere so i decided to ask for pointers. Thank you for the links however, I think i overlooked 2 or 3 of those links yesterday through my sleepy haze. I also need to know how to set-up my json package and the .git files. that was my main question.

Comment: i like how more time was spent arguing the validity of this guys question rather than just answering the question.